# Copy content form all text files from a directory and write to single text file

Tags: powershell

The code below will copy content from text file to a file in directory but it will overwrite the existing file content:

```
Get-ChildItem $FilePath -Recurse -Include *.docx,*folder\abc\source.txt | ForEach-Object {Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination C:\destination.txt}
```

I want to append all the content to a single file.

Comment: what you are doing is copying the files that your get-childitem returns, not their content. to get the content of a file use `get-content`. i would also propose that you use get-help and research the functions you use and what they do. you could try something like that `Get-ChildItem $FilePath -Recurse -Include *.docx,*folder\abc\source.txt | ForEach-Object { $_ | out-file C:\destination.txt -append}`

Comment: Note that **you cannot combine `*.docx` files just by concatenating them**.  This method would work for plain text files, but does not work meaningfully for Office, PDF, or other files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Get-Content` and `Add-Content` instead of `Copy-Item`:

```psh
Get-ChildItem $FilePath -Recurse -Include *.txt | ? {
  $_.FullName -like '*folder\abc\source.txt'
} | Get-Content | Add-Content 'C:\destination.txt'
```

**Edit:** As @BaconBits correctly pointed out in the comments to your question you cannot simply concatenate Word documents and text files, because the former are binary files (zip archives containing a bunch of XML files, actually). However, if you want just the (text) content of the document appended, you could do something like this:

```psh
$wd = New-Object -COM 'Word.Application'

Get-ChildItem $FilePath -Recurse | ? {
  $_.Extension -eq '.docx' -or
  $_.FullName -like '*folder\abc\source.txt'
} | % {
  $path = $_.FullName
  switch ($_.Extension) {
    '.docx' { 
              $doc = $wd.Documents.Open($path)
              $doc.Content.Text
              $doc.Close()
            }
    '.txt'  { Get-Content $path }
  }
} | Add-Content 'C:\destination.txt'

$wd.Quit()
```

**Note:** I was unable to get `Get-ChildItem` to work with partial paths in the `-Include` parameter, so I moved those conditions to a `Where-Object` filter.

Comment: @Sursh Please, please take note of Bacon Bits' comment to your question. While Ansgar's answer is (as always) spot on, it's really theory and not necessarily practice since Get-Content/Add-Content with .docx (or other non-txt files) is going to most likely have unfavorable results.

Comment: Thanks i will test and let you know

Comment: i tested script is executing even though  *.docx,*folder\abc\source.txt doesnt exist it writes something to the file

Comment: How would we paste the filename before the text?